# Whats the most pythonic / efficient way to fix this list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list:

```
dummyData =[
            {'ticker':'AAPL', 'side':'Buy', 'signal_1':211.12, 'signal_2':0, 'signal_3':0, 'last':200.12},
            {'ticker':'AAPL', 'side':'Buy', 'signal_1':0, 'signal_2':0, 'signal_3':211.12, 'last':200.12},
            {'ticker':'NFLX', 'side':'Sell', 'signal_1':411.12, 'signal_2':0, 'signal_3':0, 'last':455.02},
            {'ticker':'SPY', 'side':'Buy', 'signal_1':0, 'signal_2':211.12, 'signal_3':0, 'last':259.55},
            {'ticker':'MSFT', 'side':'Sell', 'signal_1':160.33, 'signal_2':0, 'signal_3':0, 'last':110.14},
            {'ticker':'MSFT', 'side':'Sell', 'signal_1':0, 'signal_2':161.71, 'signal_3':0, 'last':110.14},
            {'ticker':'MSFT', 'side':'Sell', 'signal_1':0, 'signal_2':0, 'signal_3':170, 'last':110.14},
            {'ticker':'SPY', 'side':'Sell', 'signal_1':300, 'signal_2':0, 'signal_3':0, 'last':259.55},
        ]
```

The **goal** is to merge the items that have the same `ticker` and `side`. The resulting list should look like:

```
resultData =[
            {'ticker':'AAPL', 'side':'Buy', 'signal_1':211.12, 'signal_2':0, 'signal_3':211.12, 'last':200.12},
            {'ticker':'NFLX', 'side':'Sell', 'signal_1':411.12, 'signal_2':0, 'signal_3':0, 'last':455.02},
            {'ticker':'SPY', 'side':'Buy', 'signal_1':0, 'signal_2':211.12, 'signal_3':0, 'last':259.55},
            {'ticker':'MSFT', 'side':'Sell', 'signal_1':160.33, 'signal_2':161.71, 'signal_3':170, 'last':110.14},
            {'ticker':'SPY', 'side':'Sell', 'signal_1':300, 'signal_2':0, 'signal_3':0, 'last':259.55},
        ]
```

Explanation:

- The first 2 rows get merged into 1. Both have the same ticker `AAPL` and the same side `Buy`.
- The row with the `NFLX` ticker stays as it is. There's not any other row with the same ticker and the same side
- The forth row with `SPY` as ticker and `Buy` as side stays as it is. The last row has the same ticker but different side
- The 3 rows with `MSFT` as ticker get merged into one. All 3 rows have the same ticker `MSFT` and the same side `Sell`

As you can see the merged rows mantain the same ticker, side and last fields. If one row has signal_1 = 100 and the other row has signal_1 = 0, the merged row would result in signal_1 = 100. If both have signal_1 = 0, the merged field stays as it is.

Ticker, side and last fields stay the same. Only the signal fields get modified.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You seem to have missed an important step: what is the logic of the merged values? Why do `211.12` and `0` become `211.12` yet `200.12` and `200.12` stay `200.12`

Comment: If both are equal they stay the same, if one is 0 and the other is 211.12, the merged field keeps the value which is not 0

Comment: What *inefficient* way have  you tried so far?

Comment: Ticker, side and last fields always stay the same. Only the signal fields get merged

Comment: @chepner with 2 for loops

Comment: I don't think there's any way around having at least two loops either explicitly or implicitly in comprehensions. One of the loops has to resolve the fields of dictionaries in the same group.

Comment: I've updated the algorithm in my post (at the bottom). A sorted list is needed for `groupby()` to maximize its groupings - the new version accounts for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this, I'm sure. This is one option using `groupby()`. `groupby()` returns an iterator, so it's evaluation is lazy and doesn't iterate over the list independently.

*An updated version of this algorithm is posted at the bottom of this answer. The new version doesn't assume that records keyed on two attributes are adjacent. Adjacent keys are needed for `groupby()` to maximize its groupings. It may be coincidental that the sample data was adjacently organized.*

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>>
>>> def fix_list(inp):
...     new_li = []
...     for _, group in groupby(inp, key=itemgetter('ticker', 'side')):
...         new_d = next(group)
...         for d in group:
...             # This block is skipped if there's only one 
...             # item in the group.
...             for k, v in d.items():
...                 new_d[k] = new_d[k] or v
...         new_li.append(new_d)
...     return new_li
...     
>>> fix_list(dummyData)
[{'ticker': 'AAPL', 'side': 'Buy', 'signal_1': 211.12, 'signal_2': 0, 'signal_3': 211.12, 'last': 200.12}, 
 {'ticker': 'NFLX', 'side': 'Sell', 'signal_1': 411.12, 'signal_2': 0, 'signal_3': 0, 'last': 455.02}, 
 {'ticker': 'SPY', 'side': 'Buy', 'signal_1': 0, 'signal_2': 211.12, 'signal_3': 0, 'last': 259.55}, 
 {'ticker': 'MSFT', 'side': 'Sell', 'signal_1': 160.33, 'signal_2': 161.71, 'signal_3': 170, 'last': 110.14}, 
 {'ticker': 'SPY', 'side': 'Sell', 'signal_1': 300, 'signal_2': 0, 'signal_3': 0, 'last': 259.55}]
>>>
```

I experimented and had three versions of the above function - trying various ways to tune the algorithm. The one I posted is the fastest. The times below are the version I started with, and the one I ended with.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("first_impl(data)", globals=globals(), number=1000000)
21.083179871027824
>>> timeit.timeit("last_impl(data)", globals=globals(), number=1000000)
5.915724034013692
```

I'm running on a VM on a host that's over ten years old. I'm sure anyone can get better times than this.

I find it interesting that even `itemgetter()` plays a part in reducing the run time of the function. I tested each line against alternatives.

The function has a side-effect. Some dictionaries in the original list will be modified.

An update here. Someone pointed out to me that `groupby()` groups adjacent keyed items in lists, so a sort would be needed for a more rigorous general solution. We get the same result with the data set in the example, but assuming that the items in other data sets might not be adjacent is possible, this version should handle it. Sorting is very fast (timsort algorithm) and only adds a little over a second to the time above.

```
>>> def fix_list(inp):
...     new_li = []
...     getter = itemgetter('ticker', 'side')
...     inp.sort(key=getter)
...     for _, group in groupby(inp, key=getter):
...         new_d = next(group)
...         for d in group:
...             # This block is skipped if there's only one
...             # item in the group.
...             for k, v in d.items():
...                 new_d[k] = new_d[k] or v
...         new_li.append(new_d)
...     return new_li
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create a `set` of ticker/side combinations.

```
combis = set((r['ticker'], r['side']) for r in dummyData)
```

The use a list comprehension to subset the data for each combo:

```
resultdata = []

for ticker, side in combis:
    # sub contains all records for this particular combination.
    sub = [r for r in dummyData if r['ticker'] == ticker and r['side'] == side]
    num = len(sub)
    if num == 0:
        continue
    elif num == 1:
        resultdata.append(sub[0])
    else:
        # TODO: merge the data from sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add another solution to this problem using Pandas. It's surprisingly easy to group the rows together... (not everything is easier with Pandas though - in a lot of cases if you have to perform a lot of changes to field data and dataframe structure it can be complicated).

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dummyData)
>>> df
  ticker  side  signal_1  signal_2  signal_3    last
0   AAPL   Buy    211.12      0.00      0.00  200.12
1   AAPL   Buy      0.00      0.00    211.12  200.12
2   NFLX  Sell    411.12      0.00      0.00  455.02
3    SPY   Buy      0.00    211.12      0.00  259.55
4   MSFT  Sell    160.33      0.00      0.00  110.14
5   MSFT  Sell      0.00    161.71      0.00  110.14
6   MSFT  Sell      0.00      0.00    170.00  110.14
7    SPY  Sell    300.00      0.00      0.00  259.55
>>>
>>> df = df.groupby(['ticker', 'side'], as_index=False).max()
>>> df
  ticker  side  signal_1  signal_2  signal_3    last
0   AAPL   Buy    211.12      0.00    211.12  200.12
1   MSFT  Sell    160.33    161.71    170.00  110.14
2   NFLX  Sell    411.12      0.00      0.00  455.02
3    SPY   Buy      0.00    211.12      0.00  259.55
4    SPY  Sell    300.00      0.00      0.00  259.55
>>>
```

Then if you need the data in the form of a list of `dict`s as in the example output:

```
>>> df.to_dict('records')
```

Comment: Nice finding! this is exactly what I was looking for. Interesting that the version with two for loops is much more efficient than the pandas one for this small dataset.

Comment: There's a lot of iterations over the data set going on behind the scenes in that simple line of code. I hadn't timed it before, so I just tried it out of curiosity. Even starting with the data as a pandas dataframe, and not converting the resultant dataframe to a dict, the pandas solution completes `1,000` iterations in roughly the time it takes my other solution to perform `1,000,000` iterations. That's a huge difference. You know, I thought pandas was optimized to perform these kinds of operations fast - I've changed my mind about that. @eddie Maybe pandas does better on larger data sets.